# Transfer observer from server to client

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, rxjs, nestjs

I want to transfer the observer from my server to the client. To further subscribe to it.

```
    @SubscribeMessage('createTodo')
    public handleCreateTodo(
        @MessageBody() data: IDataForCreateTodo,
        @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
    ): Observable<WsResponse> {
        const dataOfTodo: ICreateTodo = {
            title: data.title,
            userId: data.user.id,
        };
        const newTodo$: Observable<ITodo> = from(this.todoService.saveTodo(dataOfTodo));
        console.log(newTodo$);
        this.logger.log('Todo created');
        return of({ event: 'createdTodo', data: newTodo$ });
    }
```

I plan to accept an observer.

```
    const createTodo = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('createTodo', { title });
        socket.on('createdTodo', newTtodo => {
            console.log(newTtodo);
            newTtodo.subscribe(todo => {
                console.log(todo);
            });
            setTodos([...todos, newTtodo]);
            setLoader(false);
        });
    };
```

But I get an error message.

> Uncaught TypeError: newTtodo.subscribe is not a function at Socket.

I output the object to the console on the server.

```
Observable { 
    _isScalar: false,
    _subscribe: [Function]
}
```

[image]
Function in place all right.

I output the object to the console on the client that came to me through the socket.

```
{
    _isScalar: false
}
```

[image]
And it does not contain the function to subscribe to it.

Why am I not getting the subscription function?

I installed the rxjs library on the client, on the client I use react and for server i use nestjs.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is simply not possible. The data that will be exchanged between client and server is basically plain text – in case of JSON it's a [serialized object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serialization).

Since a function or object instance requires not just its own properties (= state, serializable) but also the current context (not serializable), it can not be serialized as a whole but just a part of it: its state.